# When does the database actually get queried in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say you have this code:

```
products = session.query(Products)
query = products.filter(Products.productVendor == 'Classic Metal Creations')

for q in query:
    print q
```

When is the database queried? How many times is the database queried here?

So for example. when we do a `filter()` on `products`, are we just performing that operation client-side on the result set that we got from the original query?

Answer (score 1):

The database is actually queried when you iterate through `query`, i.e. the line `for q in query`. This includes calling `all()`, `first()`, `scalar()`, etc. on the query. `filter()` only generatively modifies the query to include the filter.

Comment: So to make this clear, every time you iterate through a query, you query the database? This means that the only way to iterate through the exact same result set is by doing a `.all()` on the query and iterating through that.

Comment: @joshualan Yes, exactly.